# .NET RSA Encryption: Minimum keysize?

Tags: .net, encryption, key, rsa

I can load a 128bit RSA key in .NET, and use it for decryption. But I cannot seem to generate 128bit (or lower) keys, i always get the error 'Invalid flags specified'. When I try 512bits as keysize, everything works fine. So is 512bits the minimum keysize for .NET?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific as to what API you're using?

Comment: Why do you care? RSA keys below 512 bit are totally broken.

Comment: @CodeInChaos I needed to make a tradeoff: longer keysizes result in longer signatures (more storage), and slower verification (more CPU). With millions of signatures to verify there was no other option than 384 bits for my specific use case. And that 512 has been broken by university super computers, does not mean the average consumer can break it within a day.

Comment: @Joshua Did you look into elliptic curves? In particular ECDSA? This allows much shorter signatures.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each [AsymmetricAlgorithm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.asymmetricalgorithm.aspx) and [SymmetricAlgorithm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5b5ddwt.aspx) has a property [LegalKeySizes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.legalkeysizes.aspx) that can help you determine if a key size is valid for the algorithm.  From the links you can print out the valid key sizes for the algorithm you are using:

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
for (int i = 0; i < rsa.LegalKeySizes.Length; i++)
{
   KeySizes key_size = rsa.LegalKeySizes[i];
   Console.WriteLine(String.Format("[Key Size {0}] - min: {1}, max: {2}, step: {2}",
      i, key_size.MinSize, key_size.MaxSize, key_size.SkipSize));
}
```

For [RSACryptoServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.aspx), this will print:

> [Key Size 0] - min: 384, max: 16384, step: 16384

Answer (score 6):

512 bits is (technically) a minimum size of RSA key, but it's not secure. Nowadays 1024 bits are the absolute minimum and 2048 bits are recommended.

Note, that 1024 bits in RSA corresponds in security level to 128 bits of symmetric algorithm. Maybe you confused these values, thinking that 128 bits are the same for asymmetric and symmstric encryption, but no, they aren't.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the recommended key size. Using 128 bit RSA key is certainly not wise...

Comment: `openssl genrsa` doesn't complain until I get down to *30 bits*.

Comment: @l0b0 That's openssl's problem.